# How can i make substitutions of the same word in Perl on the same xml line?

Tags: perl, if-statement, substitution, uppercase

I'm working on an XML Document, I need to open it and transform to uppercase some specific tag values on the same line. If I have the same word it only does the substitution for one of them although I'm using two different if loops:
This is my XML:

```
<pageID="1" width="827" height="1169" Sender_Company="société" Sender_Address="société" Sender_Fax="" Category="C2" Language_2="" Document_Object="" Language_1="french" Language_3="" NumPage="1" Script_1="typed">
```

This is my code:

```
while (<FILEIN>) {
    if ($_ =~ /pageID="1"/) {
        $haschanged = 1;
        if ($_ !~ /Sender_Address=""/) {
            if ($_ =~ /(Sender_Address="(.*?)")/){
                my $SenderAddress = $2;
                $SenderAddress = uc($SenderAddress);
                $_ =~ s/$1/Sender_Address="$SenderAddress"/;
            }
        }

        if ($_ !~ /Sender_Company=""/) { 
            if ($_ =~ /(Sender_Company="(.*?)")/) { 
                my $SenderCompany = $2;
                $SenderCompany = uc($SenderCompany);
                $_ =~ s/$1/Sender_Company="$SenderCompany"/;
                #print "$_\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use two different values for `Sender_Company="bla"` and `Sender_Address="société"` the transformation to uppercase works but when I use in this case the same word `Sender_Company="société"` and `Sender_Address="société"` it doesn't do the transformation to uppercase.
Does anyone have any ideas? I can't find the logic behind it not wanting to transform the same  word when I'm using two distinct if loops at a time. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to indent your code properly. That will help you to find problems in general and it's a bit of respect for the readers mainly  when you ask help.

Comment: Use an XML parser to manipulate XML.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the original xml file. Not just print it and it doesn't transform the the values when it's the same words.It only transforms one word. When I print it on the terminal, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of XML is a bit debatable:

1. That isn't XML. It is an XML fragment at most (Element not closed, tag name can't double as attribute like `<pageID="1">`, no `<?xml ...?>` declaration, no root element, …)
2. Don't parse XML with regexes ;-)
3. XML doesn't have a concept of “lines”.

Besides of that, the code should work fine. Do note that you can make your life easy, and your code short:

1. `$_ =~ /foo/` is the same as `/foo/`, `$_ !~ /foo/` is the same as `!/foo/`.
2. Instead of extracting two captures, and substituting the result in a second regex, you can do it all in just one step:

   ```
   s{ (?<=Sender_Address=") ([^"]+) (?=") }{ uc $1 }ex
   ```

   Wait, what? I extract one or more non-"-characters that are preceded by the string `Sender_Address="` and are followed by `"` (look-around assertions). The thing in between I capture, and substitute it with an uppercased version. Because I match at least one character, I don't have to test for the empty tag case. The `/e` flag allows code in the substitution (not really neccessary here), and the `/x` allows us to include nonmatching whitespace for better formatting.

   You can easily extend this for both attributes you want to uppercase:

   ```
   # This subsumes your whole logic inside `if (/pageID="1"/)`
   $haschanged = 1;
   for my $attr (qw/Sender_Address Sender_Company/) {
     s{ (?<=\Q$attr\E=") ([^"]+) (?=") }{ uc $1 }ex;
   }
   ```

   The `\Q...\E` causes the interpolated stuff to match literally, even if it contains characters that would be regex metacharacters otherwise.

There are a few remaining bugs:

1. You fail to uppercase characters that are given as entities.
2. XML allows single quotes `'...'` to be used as tag value delimiters. You don't handle them
3. See the points under *Your understanding of XML*…

All of these can be solved by using an XML parser, and then transforming the attributes in the DOM.